# Channel ManagedChannelImpl{logId=1, target=photoslibrary.googleapis.com:443} was not shutdown properly

Tags: java, google-photos, google-photos-api

Has anyone experienced this error with Google Photos SDK for Java:

```
SEVERE: *~*~*~ Channel ManagedChannelImpl{logId=1, target=photoslibrary.googleapis.com:443} was not shutdown properly!!! ~*~*~*
    Make sure to call shutdown()/shutdownNow() and wait until awaitTermination() returns true.
java.lang.RuntimeException: ManagedChannel allocation site
    at io.grpc.internal.ManagedChannelOrphanWrapper$ManagedChannelReference.<init>(ManagedChannelOrphanWrapper.java:94)
    at io.grpc.internal.ManagedChannelOrphanWrapper.<init>(ManagedChannelOrphanWrapper.java:52)
    at io.grpc.internal.ManagedChannelOrphanWrapper.<init>(ManagedChannelOrphanWrapper.java:43)
    at io.grpc.internal.AbstractManagedChannelImplBuilder.build(AbstractManagedChannelImplBuilder.java:514)
    at com.google.api.gax.grpc.InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.createSingleChannel(InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.java:223)
    at com.google.api.gax.grpc.InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.createChannel(InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.java:164)
    at com.google.api.gax.grpc.InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.getTransportChannel(InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.java:156)
    at com.google.api.gax.rpc.ClientContext.create(ClientContext.java:157)
    at com.google.photos.library.v1.internal.stub.GrpcPhotosLibraryStub.create(GrpcPhotosLibraryStub.java:286)
    at com.google.photos.library.v1.internal.stub.PhotosLibraryStubSettings.createStub(PhotosLibraryStubSettings.java:264)
    at com.google.photos.library.v1.internal.InternalPhotosLibraryClient.<init>(InternalPhotosLibraryClient.java:180)
    at com.google.photos.library.v1.PhotosLibraryClient.<init>(PhotosLibraryClient.java:101)
    at com.google.photos.library.v1.PhotosLibraryClient.initialize(PhotosLibraryClient.java:114)
```

What's the workaround for this?